# AppCompatActivity instead of ComponentActivity in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, appcompatactivity

I want to open `datePicker` dialog on a button click in Jetpack compose.
For that, I am using the below code inside the button's `onClick` action.

```
val context = LocalContext.current
Button(onClick = {
    (context as AppCompatActivity).let {
        val picker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker().build()
        picker.show(it.supportFragmentManager, picker.toString())
        picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
            // some code
        }
    }
})
```

If I am using the `ComponentActivity`, `supportFragmentManager` is not supported.
Is it fine to extend the activity from `AppCompatActivity`?
Or is there any other way, I can get the solution if the above-mentioned solution is not correct?

Comment: Also consider starring this issue about Compose-based date-/time-pickers to add your vote: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197942880

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `AppCompatActivity` since it extends `FragmentActivity` which extends `ComponentActivity`.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
           val activity = LocalContext.current as AppCompatActivity
                Button(onClick={ showDatePicker(activity)}){
                Text("Picker")
           }
        }
    }
}

fun showDatePicker(activity: AppCompatActivity){
    val picker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker().build()
    activity?.let {
        picker.show(it.supportFragmentManager, picker.toString())
        picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** it requires at least the `AppCompat 1.3.0` version.