# MaterialDatePicker in Jetpack compose in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show Date Picker and Time Picker when i click on Buttons. I did not see any examples on Date Picker in Jetpack Compose.

How to use the MaterialDatePicker in Android with Jetpack Compose with out any 3rd party library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67364372/appcompatactivity-instead-of-componentactivity-in-jetpack-compose/67364675#67364675