# Jetpack Compose Material date range picker

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm having trouble with this code line to show a date range picker with android compose:

```
dateRangePicker.show(, "date_range_picker")
```

getting this:

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
> show(FragmentManager, String?) defined in com.google.android.material.datepicker.MaterialDatePicker
> show(FragmentTransaction, String?) defined in com.google.android.material.datepicker.MaterialDatePicker

Any one had an idea what is happening?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67364372/appcompatactivity-instead-of-componentactivity-in-jetpack-compose

Comment: Looks like you're missing first argument which should be context. How to get context you can see in Gabriele's mentioned question, also you need to update your activity to `AppCompatActivity`, as Gabriele said in his answer